# Get String from TextBox and compare

Tags: objective-c, string, comparison

I'm trying something like my first comparison App in Obj-C and i'm already running into trouble.

Well, there is a textBox with `unamebox:(id)unb` and a textfield `NSTextField*  myOut;`

Well, here was my first try:

```
if ([unb stringValue] == @"hello") {  
    [myOut setStringValue:(NSString *)@"hello dude"];  
}  
else {  
    [myOut setStringValue:(NSString *)@"What?"];  
}
```

To my shame, this always setzt the text field to "What?"
When I try the isEqualtoString, it doesn't even do anything:

```
if ([unb isEqualToString:(NSString*)@"hello"]) {
    [myOut setStringValue:(NSString *)@"hello dude"];
}
else {
    [myOut setStringValue:(NSString *)@"What?"];
}
```

So, what shall I do to compare it?

by the way, I already read the links which were suggested above. If I missed anything important, I'm sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-isEqualToString:` is a method on an NSString, not on an NSTextField. You should be getting an error from sending that message.

You want this:

```
[[unb stringValue] isEqualToString:@"hello"]
```

Comment: Alright, I'm not getting an error when trying to compile the version below

Your version works now, thank you a lot
(Since my reputation is not high enough, I can't vode up, sorry)